# Simple: How can I concatenate more elements of struct arrays in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, concatenation, element

I have the following array k defined as a struct array of coordinates, i.e. k={{x1,y1},{x2,y2}}.
If I'd like to add one more coordinate to this struct array, what notation would I use? the pseudocode would be k=k+{x3,y3}  and the result would be {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3}}. As a Python coder, I have trouble with the syntax of Matlab.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that you have a structure that already contains a `x` and `y` coordinate and you have a master structure that contains your other coordinates, which is `k` in your case.  Here's an example structure that contains two points where each structure has two fields: `x` and `y`:

```
k(1).x = 10;
k(1).y = 20;
k(2).x = 20;
k(2).y = 30;
```

If you have another point:

```
pt.x = 40;
pt.y = 50;
```

... to concatenate this point onto your structure `k`, it's simply:

```
k = [k pt];
```

This is the most common way to concatenate a structure to a larger list of structures.

---

As proof, let's look at the `x` and `y` coordinates before and after the concatenation:

```
>> xvals = [k.x]

xvals =

    10    20

>> yvals = [k.y]

yvals =

    20    30

>> pt.x = 40;
>> pt.y = 50;
>> k = [k pt];
>> xvals = [k.x]

xvals =

    10    20    40

>> yvals = [k.y]

yvals =

    20    30    50
```

Answer (score 0):

With your notation you created an cell array containing cells. This is different to a struct in matlab. If you want to stick to cell arrays you can add a third by

```
k(end+1) = {x3,y3}
```

For structs in matlab @rayryeng just answered.